# Copy boot partition from one disk to another

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I'm currently facing a hardware HD problem.

One of my HDs has semi-died. It works, kind of; data is being read, but once in awhile now and then, it decides to not respond for a while.
Windows hangs for a few seconds, and sometimes I get an event in my event log saying that the device didn't respond fast enough, or something to that effect.

Now I got a new HD to replace it, but I'd love not to reinstall Windows.
Are there any tools that can copy a partition "bit-to-bit" from one HD to another so that I can swap the HDs, and it'll still boot up, and everything will work as if nothing had happened?

I'm assuming I'll be loading both HDs in another machine, so I wouldn't be copying the partition from which the system that copies them has booted up, but I would need it to boot up later my original machine.

Note: the new HDD I bought is bigger than the old one. The old one is 160Gb, and the new one is 500Gb.
However, all I care about is a 20Gb partition in the original one, the one that boots up. For the 140Gb partition, I can copy files manually. Or, if a program will copy everything exactly and leave 2 partitions (20 / 140 Gb) in the new HD, and I can create a 3rd one for the rest of the space, that's perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Norton Ghost is the traditional commercial tool for this purpose.

Personally, I'm skint, so I use a Linux live CD that has [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) on it. GParted can copy, move and resize partitions, so you can copy the partition to the new disk then resize it to fit.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a linux system laying around you can use DD, it should be built in.

Answer (score 1):

[SystemRescueDisk](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) can do smart (compression aware, empty spare aware) copies of paritions to local media or network shares. Saved my butt several times.

Answer (score 0):

**[XXCopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm)** is great for that, partition by partition, as described [here](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy10.htm).

```
XXCOPY C:\ D:\  /CLONE
```

[image]